# postorder traverse of a dom tree

Tags: java, dom

If there is an XML file called **a.xml**, is there any way to traverse its DOM tree in
postorder fashion?

I tried using **GetNextSiblings** method but it didn't work. Any idea?

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
       <title text="title1"> 
           <comment id="comment1">
               <data> abcd </data>
               <data> efgh </data>
           </comment>
           <comment id="comment2">
               <data> ijkl </data>
               <data> mnop </data>
               <data> qrst </data>
           </comment>
       </title>
```

And here is my code to traverse it:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.w3c.dom.traversal.DocumentTraversal;
import org.w3c.dom.traversal.NodeFilter;
import org.w3c.dom.traversal.NodeIterator;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Newtraverse {
public static Node check(Node node){
    Node c=node;
    // Node c = null;
    if (node!=null)
        if (node.hasChildNodes()==true &&node.getNodeName()!=null)
        {
            node=node.getFirstChild().getNextSibling();
            if (node!=null)
            {
                 System.out.println(node);

                 check(node); 
            }

            if(node==null)
            {
                c=c.getNextSibling();
                check(c);
            }
       }

    return node;
 }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        File file = new File("d:\\a.xml");
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =
  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document document = db.parse(file);
  document.getDocumentElement().normalize();


  Node b=document.getFirstChild();

 Node result= check(b);
}
}
```

And here is the output:

```
[comment: null]
[data: null]
```

As you all can see, it just traverses two tags. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how your check method should like (I didn't run it though...)

```
public static void check(Node node){
  if (node == null || node.getNodeName() == null)
    return;

  // Do PostOrder on all children
  check(node.getFirstChild());  

  // Now that all children were traversed, process the current node:
  System.out.println(node); 

  // Do PostOrder on following siblings
  check(node.getNextSibling();  
}
```

Comment: that's nice! but there is a little problem,   the result looks like this:
run:
[#text:  
           ]
[#text: 
               ]
[#text:  abcd ]
[data: null]
[#text: 
               ]
[#text:  efgh ]
[data: null]
[#text: 
           ]
[comment: null]
[#text: 
           ]
[#text: 
               ]
[#text:  ijkl ]
[data: null]
[#text: 
               ]
[#text:  mnop ]
[data: null]
[#text: 
               ]
[#text:  qrst ]
[data: null]
[#text: 
           ]
[comment: null]
[#text: 
       ]
[title: null]
could you tell me, how can I get rid of the #text with no content?

Comment: Try replacing `System.out.println(node)` with something like: `System.out.println(node.getNodeValue() != null & node.getNodeValue().trim().length() == 0 ? "" : node)`

Comment: thanks, but there is a little problem for **node.getNodeValue().trim().length() == 0**  part, it said NullPointer Exception. and could you tell me what is [#text]=""?why there are such results?

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing `&` in my code. Here's the correct version: `System.out.println(node.getNodeValue() != null && node.getNodeValue().trim().length() == 0 ? "" : node)`. The empty Text node are there because all sorts of blanks/newlines that exist in your XML document.

Comment: oh i got it. would you mind to answer my last question? in the code you sent here as an answer, i can't understand one thing. when it goes down, then it begins going through its siblings, but when it's in last siblings that doesnt have any child node too, how it goes to it's parent node? maybe my question looks silly. :P

Comment: The recursion ends so it gets back to the next-to-last sibling and which immediately returns so it goes back to the next-to-next-to-last etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your `check` function does this:

- Given null, do nothing.
- Given a non-null node with children, take its second child node, print it and check it.
- If it has fewer than two child nodes, check its next sibling

So, You start by checking `title`,

- `title`'s second child is the `comment` element with three `data` child elements.

  - Print out "comment", and check the `comment` node.
- That element has three child nodes, the second child is the `data` element with content "mnop".

  - Print out "data", and check the `data` node.
- That element only has one child node, so check its next sibling
- That element only has one child node, so try to check its next sibling (which it doesn't have, therefore `null`)
- Do nothing, and return up the stack.

You can fix this by not skipping the first child node every time.  You may also wish to loop over the child nodes, recursing the next level each time, rather than using recursion for everything.

Comment: oh, it seems quite complex, i wish if u could try to give a code too

Comment: The complexity is all yours.  All I have done is render your code in prose and describe the error.  If you were simply to read it, then you'd see where the problem is, and be able to author the appropriate correction yourself.